# primary keys in form for post-back?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.NET mvc 3 with razor website. I have a web page that is displaying a list of data from a database in a form such as:

```
<input type="text" name="blah1" value="blah" />
<input type="text" name="blah2" value="blahblah" />
<input type="text" name="blah3" value="blahblah" />
```

Each row above is assoicated with a primary key. When the user hits submit and posts back the FormCollection to the controller.. how do I go about getting the primary keys of each blah? Do I add a hidden field for each row that contains the primary key of that row? If so, how do I know which blah it is associated with as the FormCollection is just a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you using a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your controller action you would send a list of those models to the view:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new[]
        {
            new MyViewModel { Id = "1", Text = "blah" },
            new MyViewModel { Id = "2", Text = "blahblah" },
            new MyViewModel { Id = "3", Text = "blahblah" },
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<MyViewModel> model)
    {
        // Here you will get a collection of id and text for each item
        ...
    }
}
```

and the view you could use hidden fields for the id and a textbox for the value:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

and the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MyViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Text)
```